# How to Add a Placeholder in Macro Script in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

When we are going to write a macro in TeXstudio, I know we can add a place holder by using `%<%>` in normal mode, but if we switch to script mode this command does not work in TeXstudio.

What command we should use to add a place holder in script mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Hopefully someone will be able to answer your question (I don't use TeXstudio).  In the mean time, you could not find a similar existing implementation?

Comment: This functionality is currently not exposed in the scripting interface of TeXstudio. You may open a feature request.

Comment: Does the comment on https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1002/ solve your issue? You (or if you prefer, I) could write an answer then and close this post here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi yes you can write here

Answer (score 2):

There is the `editor.insertSnippet()` command you can invoke in script mode. The placeholder commands work as expected.

For example:

```
%SCRIPT
editor.insertSnippet("\\includegraphics{%<%:id:1%>}\n\\label{fig:%<%:mirror,id:1%>}")
```

yields

[image: placeholders]