# What is TeXStudio's red box (placeholder) for?

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

When I autocomplete an environment, I get a red box (which I now know, from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130157/31839) is called a placeholder.)

[image: content placeholder]
[image: content placeholder with content]

What are these placeholders for, what functionality is associated with them, and what is the intended workflow for using them?

*(I think this information is probably all on here somewhere, spread over a series of different questions/answers. But it would be great to have everything in one place and to know I'm not missing anything)*

Comment: Have you read http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION113?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That's a useful link, thanks. I'm not certain it covers every piece of functionality associated with placeholders. (For example, it says nothing about pressing Enter to clear them.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Placeholders are mostly used to indicate arguments when commands are autocompleted: under what conditions these appear can be controlled via `cwl` files.

By designating where these placeholders go, you will be able to quickly jump from one argument to the next using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>, which is meant to make typesetting your documents more efficient. (Compare this to when there are no placeholders available.)

For example:

[image: pic1]

When you're done typing the arguments in the placeholders, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to remove the placeholders (i.e., the boxes in question).

Another useful property of the placeholders (which can be customized, particularly in user macros) is the **mirror property**.
With this, you can set two (or more) placeholders to have the same content.
You can see this in action with one of the default keyboard shortcuts in TeXstudio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, which is a shortcut to create `\begin{}`/`\end{}` environments.

[image: pic2]

Here I use the following keyboard shortcut sequence:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to create the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to jump to the next placeholder; and enter the document body (highlighting the `content` placeholder name for easy replacement with my own text)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to create the `align`/`equation` environment
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> to jump to the next placeholder; and enter the `equation` environment body
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to remove placeholders.

Such functionalities and properties of the placeholders are made available to the TXS user to use in their own user macros as well. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407641/117534) for an example. <sup>(Sorry for the unintentional self-plug--it's easier to find examples from my own previous answers.)</sup>

In the same vein: TXS is intelligent enough to highlight the placeholders when your cursor is left on relevant content for a short while. By 'highlight the placeholders', I mean the re-boxing of the commands as seen in the gif.
(The actual highlighting of `equation`, I used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.)

This allows you to (using the properties of placeholders) replace contents in mirrored placeholders quickly and simultaneously (once again, for efficiency purposes).

[image: pic3]

All other related properties to the 'placeholder' function are stated in the [TXS manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33), Sect 4.5.1 on Text macros (which I won't elaborate on here).

Comment: Nice! One learns something everyday (+1). Though I always mess up the use of "Ctrl + Left/Right" for this is somehow built-in in my brain to jump between words and I end up jumping more than desired every time I fill in a bibentry. Still, the feature is very nice indeed overall.

Comment: Thank you! :) I don't use the "Ctrl+L/R" too much during typesetting sessions myself as well.

Comment: Wow. I think this is the best answer I've ever seen on this StackExchange...

Comment: And today I learned some more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410484/105447. And got rid of that annoying shortcut in the process!  :)