# Synchronisation of parameters between \begin and \end

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

If I create a new object that requires

```
\begin{}
```

and

```
\end{}
```

I want the contents within the braces to auto-synchronise with each other.

For example

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Example text
\end{itemize}
```

And later I decide that I want an enumerated list, and I change one of the contents inside the { } to enumerate the other one should too automatically.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Example text

% Contents of {} should update here automatically if changed above
% Or vice versa  
\end{enumerate}
```

This 'auto-synchronization' sometimes occurs accidentally so I think it is an inbuilt feature, but I do not know how to trigger it.

---

Edit

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414948/what-is-texstudios-red-box-placeholder-for) by @Troy also explains this issue and he has used better terminology (mirroring vs auto-synchronisation). However, in that answer, the information by @Troy was additional and not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: There's a (short) time lag before TS marks both ends of the environment for simultaneous edition. Is this what you mean by accidentally?

Comment: @gusbrs by accidentally I mean the contents of the { } being edited if its partner is edited. Not sure what time-lag you are referring to

Comment: Once you place your cursor in one of the fields (e.g. `itemize`, `\begin` or `\end`) it takes a couple of seconds until TeXstudio turns them into placeholders (you'll then see a box around both of them). Once this is done, edition takes place in both of them simultaneously.

Comment: @gusbrs yes that was what I was looking for, thank you. Should I post this as an answer for completeness?

Comment: I'll post a short one then.

Comment: @IshankJuneja I covered this in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415001/117534) which you might be interested in.

Comment: @Troy I knew I had learned this from someone more knowledgeable! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXstudio recognizes both ends of environments for simultaneous edition, but has a time lag in doing so. In order to trigger it, you should place your cursor in one of the fields (e.g. `itemize`, `\begin` or `\end`) and wait a couple of seconds. After this time lag, TeXstudio turns them into placeholders (you'll then see a box around both of them). Once this is done, edition then takes place in both of them simultaneously.