# Ask for a shortcut in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

For example, when I type `\frac` and use auto-completion, I will get `\frac{num}{den}` while the `num` has been selected. But when I fill the field `num`, I have to select the field `den` myself.

So, is there a shortkey that can auto-select the `den` when I press the key?

Comment: Did you try `tab` ?

Comment: Looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414948/105447?

Comment: In my txs, it is `alt+right`. You can set it up in Options menu.

Answer (score 2):

The default should be `ctrl` + `→` or `←` (for the previous placeholder). It can be changed in the preferences: Short cuts > Editor > Basic Key Mapping > Next/Previous Placeholder.

Here’s the (german version) screenshot of the menu.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could someone with an english version pleas check if I got the right translations for the menus and replace the screenshot?! Thanks!

Comment: Just checked, it is indeed "Next placeholder" in the english version. BUt the level above is called `Basic Key Mapping`

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks for the edit :-) feel free to also change the screen shot …

Comment: Sorry, my screenshot would not help much - I heavily customised my short cuts.